# SNMP in Java, specifically to be JMX adapter

Tags: java, jmx, snmp

I have a few JAVA application that I monitor using JMX.

I would like to write an SNMP client for these applications that wraps the JMX interface and by discovery exposes the same attributes that are exposed in JMX, through SNMP.

I have no problem writing the client if I just figure out how to write SNMP clients in JAVA. Is there a free SNMP library for JAVA that I can use?
Is there a good free SNMP adapter for JMX? (Tried "`WebNMS SNMP Adapter for JMX`" trial unsuccessfully)

Thank you!

Comment: snmpadaptor4j.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SNMP4J](http://www.snmp4j.org/) is an opensoure API for SNMP in Java. You can try that.
As far as SNMP adapter for JMX is concerned, why does WebNMS not work. Did you checkout [JBossSNMPAdapter](http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/JBossSNMPAdapter)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm checking SNMP4J out (turns out "snmp java" google search brings this one up first) anhd JBossSNMPAdapter, although we are not using JBoss currently (Tomcat only) but planning to.
About WebNMS - did everything according to instruction and after running the whole thing I just didn't get any SNMP output. This being closed source and with very little documentation I did not invest alot of time trying to figure it out.

Comment: Zoho (formerly AdventNet) provides free support as a part of pre-sales activities. They are trying to be quite helpful. Try their support forum: https://forums.webnms.com/snmp-api

Answer (score 1):

Old stuff.

SNMP monitoring is built-in on Java 6.

[SNMP Monitoring and Management](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/snmp.html)

Comment: this only publishes the standard MIB for the JVM and doesn't allow to expose custom MBeans

Answer (score 1):

You also can try [SNAMP](http://snamp.bytex.solutions/) software (open source as well). It acts as a software protocol bridge between JMX and SNMP.